# How to select this in mysql?

Tags: mysql

the field value equal  to zero OR it is NULL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [fieldname] = 0 OR [fieldname] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field = 0 OR field IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There is handy function called ISNULL which allows you to return a different value if it is. You can use it like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(fieldName, -999)
FROM _table
```

Also, for your main question:

```
SELECT * FROM _table
  WHERE field IS NULL OR field = 0
```